# How to return a HTMLResponse with FastAPI

Tags: python, web, fastapi

Is it possible to display an HTML file at the endpoint?

For example the home page then the user is visiting `"/"`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, it's possible FastAPI has `HTMLResponse`.

You can return a `HTMLResponse`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_items():
    html_content = """
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Some HTML in here</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Look ma! HTML!</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)
```

You can also render templates with [Jinja2](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")


templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/items/{id}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_item(request: Request, id: str):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("item.html", {"request": request, "id": id}
```

Comment: Does this mean, we can use FastAPI to run a full fledged website?

Comment: Yes, FastAPI can run a full fledged website.