# How to serve a pyvis graph with fastapi?

Tags: networkx, fastapi, pyvis

I wonder what is the best way to serve a pyvis network with FastAPI?

[image]

This iteractive graph was generated with pyvis and is stored in an html file and then displayed as an interactive tool in JupyterLab. I would like to serve it as part of a molecular graph exploration tool. I wonder what is the best way to do so?

```
import networkx
import obonet

G = obonet.read_obo('https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/chebi/ontology/chebi_core.obo')

# Create smaller subgraph
H = nx.ego_graph(G, 'CHEBI:17710', 2)

H.nodes['CHEBI:24669']

from pyvis.network import Network

nt = Network('1500px', '1500px', notebook=True)
nt.from_nx(H)
nt.show('H.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

First thought is to serve the template using the type HTMLResponse. Just return it as is. But you may need more work to render it well. So...

Second thought, make a template with a Jinja2 base and include your content in a block, so you can take care of any set up work necessary for the display.

See more at [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296604/how-to-return-a-htmlresponse-with-fastapi), where some code is already written that I would write anyway.

Very interested in your result.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration!